# Solve $y'\cos x + y \sin x= x \sin 2x + x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a differential equation as below
$$y'\cos x + y \sin x= x \sin 2x + x^2.$$

I need some tips on how to start solving. What do I have to determine?

Homogenity, linearity, or exactness?

Comment: How about putting it in the form $y' + \ldots$ and then thinking about an integrating factor?

Comment: Did you notice that $y'\cos x + y \sin x= 0$ is perfectly separable ? Then, variation of parameters, may be.

Comment: The fact that $y'(x)\cos x+y(x)\sin x=y'(x)\cos x-y(x)(\cos x)'$ should suggest the change of variable $y(x)=z(x)\cos x$...

Answer (score 1):

Writing your DE as $$y'+y\tan x=\frac{x\sin 2x+x^2}{\cos x},$$
the integrating factor is $$I=e^{\int\tan x dx}=\sec x$$

Therefore the solution is given by $$y\sec x=\int\frac{x\sin 2x+x^2}{\cos^2 x}dx$$
$$=\int2x\tan x+x^2\sec^2 x dx$$
$$\Rightarrow y\sec x=x^2\tan x+c$$

Comment: I don't understand the last part.

Comment: Do you mean the final integration? It's recognition of an exact derivative of a product. The rest of the method is the standard approach with an integrating factor

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2 \tan x)=2x\tan x+x^2\sec^2 x$. Hence explanation for the integral, as DavidQuinn said,it is an exact derivative.

Answer (score 0):

$$y(x)\sin(x)+y'(x)\cos(x)=x^2+x\sin(2x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y'(x)+\tan(x)y(x)=x\sec(x)\left(x+\sin(2x)\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Let $\mu(x)=e^{\int\tan(x)\space\text{d}x}=\sec(x)$.

Multiply both sides by $\mu(x)$:

---

$$\sec(x)y'(x)+y(x)\left(\sec(x)\tan(x)\right)=x\sec^2(x)\left(x+\sin(2x)\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Substitute $\tan(x)\sec(x)=\frac{\text{d}\sec(x)}{\text{d}x}$:

---

$$\sec(x)y'(x)+y(x)\cdot\frac{\text{d}\sec(x)}{\text{d}x}=x\sec^2(x)\left(x+\sin(2x)\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(y(x)\sec(x)\right)=x\sec^2(x)\left(x+\sin(2x)\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(y(x)\sec(x)\right)\space\text{d}x=\int x\sec^2(x)\left(x+\sin(2x)\right)\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sec(x)y(x)=x^2\tan(x)+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Divide both sides by $\mu(x)=\sec(x)$:

---

$$y(x)=x^2\sin(x)+\text{C}\cos(x)$$